# TIN interpolation QGIS - Voronoi Polygons

Tags: qgis, interpolation, tin

[image]

I'm trying to interpolate 12 points in QGIS linear within a Voronoi Polygon using TIN-Interpolation created for the points. However,the extent of the raster layer only interpolates between the points and not the whole area of the Voronoi polygons. How do I interpolate for an entire area using 12 points?

[image]